# Como usar SUM em um campo string, convertendo o valor para int?

Tags: linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma tabela que tem um campo `PA` que é `string`, ele armazena um número de 10 dígitos e eu não posso alterar o tipo do mesmo porque faz referência a uma outra tabela.

Estou tentando somar esse campo assim:

`Int32 somaBpaC = modelOff.bpacs.Sum(p => p.pa);`

Recebo um erro já esperado de que não é possível somar o campo `pa` que é `string`.

Existe alguma forma de converter o campo para `int` na hora da soma?

Comment: modelOff.bpacs é o seu Entity Framework e o pa é um campo que é um texto, mas, que guarda numeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tentou fazer um Parse do valor:

```
Int32 somaBpaC = modelOff.bpacs.Sum(p => int.Parse(p.pa));
```

Comment: Estou recebendo o erro: >System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: tem certeza que uma string que esta retornando para fazer esse parse ali no retorno?

Comment: tenho certeza sim.